# f2py with include files

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I am compiling a fortran program called prog.f. It contains an include file called test.inc.
This below runs successfully and shows that my include file is found. I have a prog.so file generated.

```
f2py -c prog.f -m prog
```

However when I call this module from python I get this error message:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import prog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./prog.so: undefined symbol: unknown_function_
```

I suspect something to do with my compilation arguments but I am not too familiar with Fortran. Do I need to include my include file as well? If so how?

Comment: Well finally I don't know if this one will get a final answer. I stripped down lots of unnecessary code from the fortran code and got it to work that way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need the include file.  It might be something as simple as:

```
f2py -c include_file.f prog.f -m prog
```

although I haven't tested that.  Alternatively, you might need to use the fortran `include` statement to include `include_file` into `prog` ... Also, if you're more familiar with C, virtually all fortran compilers that I know use the convention that `prog.F` is fortran code that should be preprocessed by `cpp`.  So you could probably get your file included that way as well.

Comment: Thanks mgilson. I did not get much luck in that way either. The fortran code already contains the include statement to my include_file. So maybe my problem is not linked with include files.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem, and was able to find other discussions that simply stated that current f2py does not support preprocessing of files, such as #include statements and conditional compilation.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/f2py-dev/aW65sEoSdG8

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-November/046381.html

Two solutions:
Simplest:  If you are using gfortran to compile your code, rename any .f90 or .f file to .F90 or .F.  Using a capital letter keys gfortran to automatically use the preprocessor (even if you don't specify).

Second:
Use your Fortran compiler to preprocess the file and save the result as an intermediate Fortran code to be sent to f2py.

```
gfortran -E -D<Defines-for-compiler> file.f -cpp  -o outdir/file.f
```

where -E is the command to tell gfortran to just preprocess the file (may vary from compiler to compiler), and -D option to define any values to use during the preprocessing.

Saving the file to another directory (or changing the name completely) is necessary to avoid overwriting the original .f file.